# Socket.io transmits data in bursts in IE11

Tags: c++, node.js, socket.io, internet-explorer-11, node-modules

**Edit: I simplified the source code to a minimal test case to reproduce the behavior. To reproduce the behavior one needs the "index.html", "server.js" files and compile the "mycppmodule.cpp" file. They are all posted in their entirety below.**

- **IE 11 version**: 11.0.9600.18097
- **Node version**: v4.1.2

This is a somewhat mysterious problem to me and describing it is a bit difficult so bear with me.

So, I have a node.js server a very simple client website and a native node.js module that I wrote myself in C++. There is a socket.io communication between the server and the website.

This is the complete website client code, it gets an integer value from the server and updates a number on the website:

```
// index.html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var socket = io();
            var counter = 0;
            socket.on('data', function (data) {
                console.log("received" + data.counter);
                $("#id_counter").text(data.counter);
            });
        });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    Counter: <span id="id_counter"></span>
    </body>
</html>
```

On the server resides the following code (complete code):

```
// server.js
var http = require("http");
var url = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');

var mycppmodule = require('./build/Debug/mycppmodule');

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response){
    console.log('Connection');
    var path = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
    switch(path){
        case '/index.html':
            fs.readFile(__dirname + path, function(error, data){
            console.log('open ' + __dirname +  path);
                response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
                response.write(data, "utf8");
                response.end();
            });
            break;
        default:
            response.writeHead(404);
            response.write("opps this doesn't exist - 404");
            response.end();
            break;
    }
});

var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
mycppmodule.testAsync(function (counter) {
        console.log(counter);
        io.emit('data', { 'counter': counter });
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log("client connected");
});

server.listen(8001);
console.log("server running");
```

My module behaves somewhat similar to the javascript `setInterval`. It get's invoked roughly once per second. This is a simplified C++ module that shows the same behavior:

```
// mycppmodule.cpp
#include <node.h>
#include <v8.h>
#include <nan.h>

using namespace v8;

static Persistent<Function, CopyablePersistentTraits<Function>> _cb; // saving the callback function
static uv_async_t async;    //asyncronous messaging

// Some short function that will message the callback every second
void asyncWork(void *arg) {
    static int i;
    for (;;) {
        i++;
        async.data = (void*)&i;
        uv_async_send(&async);
        Sleep(1000);
    }
}

// the callback that gets called by asyncWork will then call the javascript callback
void testCallback(uv_async_t *handle) {
    Isolate* isolate = Isolate::GetCurrent();
    HandleScope scope(isolate);
    int counter = *((int*)handle->data);
    auto context = isolate->GetCurrentContext(); 
    auto global = context->Global(); 
    auto fn = Local<Function>::New(isolate, _cb);
    const int argc = 1;
    Handle<Value> argv[argc];
    argv[0] = Number::New(isolate, counter);
    fn->Call(global, argc, argv);   // this is where the javascript callback gets invoked
}

void testAsync(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) {
    Isolate* isolate = args.GetIsolate();
    Handle<Function> arg0 = Handle<Function>::Cast(args[0]);
    Persistent<Function> cb(isolate, arg0);
    _cb = cb;       // saving the javascript callback as persisitent
    uv_async_init(uv_default_loop(), &async, testCallback);
    uv_thread_t thread_id;
    uv_thread_create(&thread_id, asyncWork, Null);
}

void init(Handle<Object> target) {
  NODE_SET_METHOD(target, "testAsync", testAsync);
}

NODE_MODULE(MyCppModule, init);
```

Here are the puzzeling bits:

- The whole thing works like charm in chrome
- On IE11 transmission happens in bursts. Nothing happens for about 30s, then all the data gets transmitted in one short burst.
- **Mysterious**: It works in IE11 as expected when I open a Chrome instance and open the website there as well i.e. the number gets update in IE11 and Chrome as expected. As soon as I close Chrome, the problem reappears.
- **Mysterious**: It works in IE11 when I use `setInterval` instead of my `testAsync` function. How does IE11 know who calls `io.emit` on the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this can be fixed by adding an acknowledgment to the `socket.io` communication.

In `index.html` I added:

```
// ....
socket.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log("received" + data.counter);
    $("#id_counter").text(data.counter);
    socket.emit('ack'); // ADDED THIS LINE 
});
// ...
```

and in `server.js` I added:

```
//...
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log("client connected");
    // ADDED THE FOLLOWING THREE LINES
    socket.on('ack', function () { 
        console.log('received');
    })
});
//...
```

The whole thing is still a bit mysterious to me, but it works now :)